# Creating custom DVD for RHEL 7 with kickstart

Tags: cd, centos7, dvd, rhel7

I am trying to create a custom CD/DVD to deploy RHEL 7 with kickstart file. Here is what I did:

- Edited `isolinux.cfg` (in the ISOLinux folder) and `grub.cfg` file (in the `EFI\BOOT` folder).
- Created ISO using mkisofs.

But it is not working. Am I using correct files/method?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ISO image and put the `ks.cfg` file that you have created.
Preferably, put the `ks.cfg` file inside `ks` directory. More information can be found [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `new` command. Here is an example of what will work:

- Add the kickstart file to your download and exploded ISO.
- Run this command in the area with the ISO and kickstart and point to another location to build the ISO:

  ```
  genisoimage -r -v -V "OEL6 with KS for OVM Manager" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o OEL6U6_OVM_Manager.iso /var/www/html/Template/ISO/
  ```

Comment: Please [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer to improve its readability.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to create custom DVD from the RHEL7 page.

1. Mount the downloaded image

   ```
   mount -t iso9660 -o loop path/to/image.iso /mnt/iso
   ```
2. Create a working directory - a directory where you want to place the contents of the ISO image.

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/ISO
   ```
3. Copy all contents of the mounted image to your new working directory. Make sure to use the -p option to preserve file and directory permissions and ownership.

   ```
   cp -pRf /mnt/iso /tmp/ISO
   ```
4. Unmount the image.

   ```
   umount /mnt/iso
   ```
5. Make sure your current working directory is the top-level directory of the extracted ISO image - e.g. /tmp/ISO/iso. Create the new ISO image using genisoimage:

   ```
   genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -Volset "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -A "RHEL-7.1 Server.x86_64" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o ../NEWISO.iso .
   ```

Hope the [answer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux/version-7.1/red-hat-enterprise-linux-71-anaconda-customization-guide/#sect-images-repack) will helpful:

Answer (score -1):

I am editing my answer due to the comments posted. Here is a more comprehensive solution:

(A) You need to create the ISO properly. I found helpful information in [this URL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Pjones/BootableCDsForBIOSAndUEFI).

Here is the line that I actually ended up with, for my MBR/UEFI ISO creation:

```
mkisofs -U -A "<Volume Header>" -V "RHEL-7.1 x86_64" -volset "RHEL-7.1 x86_64" -J -joliet-long -r -v -T -x ./lost+found -o ${OUTPUT}/${HOST}.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 18755 /dir/where/sources/for/ISO/are/located
```

Be careful with the -V parameter, as it has to match what the kernel has defined for inst.stage2. In the default grub.conf included in the boot disk, it is configured to be "hd:LABEL=RHEL-7.1\x20x86_64" which matches with the settings above.

(B) You need the correct setup for EFI for RHEL7. For some reason, this has changed from RHEL6, where you could just use the /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.conf. Now it uses the /EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg. Common wisdom from [Red Hat Manuals](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-kickstart-howto.html) state to add the inst.ks= parameter to the kernel line. The grub.cfg that comes in the /EFI/BOOT directory of the RHEL7 boot iso actually has the linuxefi parameter, instead of the kernel one, I would guess they would work the same. If you are including the KS file on the CD, this should get you there. 
Good Luck!

Comment: Is this an attempt to answer the question or ask a separate one?

Comment: This is an attempt to collaborate on finding an answer, as I am working on the same issue. Most of the answer lies in the URL provided - e.g. how to create a dual boot MBR/UEFI Disk - The problem that I have is specifically with RHEL7, as it apparently does not use BOOTX64.efi and instead insists on using grubx64.efi (AFAIK).

Comment: This is probably best posted as a comment, or a separate question with a comment on this question linking to the new question. Comments are intended to be where collaboration occurs.